# Wooden cabinet for Personal Computer UPS and Micro ATX slim tower

Tags: furniture, cabinetry

Region: West Bengal; India.

I am getting a wooden cabinet built by our local furniture guy.

System:

1. UPS;Weight 4.7 kg/10.3617 pounds(as per brochure).
2. Micro ATX slim case; Weight 10 kg/22 pounds(did an average from the internet; including all components).

Plan:

1. UPS below, and PC case above, in separate cabinets. width of UPS cabinet 220 mm. Width of PC cabinet 110 mm. Depth of both compartments 500 mm.
2. UPS at a height of at least 250 mm from the floor, so that the furniture can be pulled back and forth while the UPS is plugged to the power socket.
3. Caster wheels at the base and brass handles in front and back(for pulling around over tiles, within the apartment room).
4. Separate compartment for external ODD.
5. Drawers below UPS.

Questions:

1. How much thickness should the weight bearing boards be?
2. Do you recommend any particular wood?
3. Any particular wheels.

Comment: This question needs some major work to be useful.  It should be split into three questions and have all the extraneous detail removed (the model of UPS is not relevant) and more information added (like how wide the shelf that will hold it is).

Comment: That said, the answers are generally:
1. Check www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/ or a similar site.  2. Whatever you like the look of, but consider plywood.  3. Anything rated to the weight you're using that won't damage the floor (too soft will scuff, too hard will chip the tile.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.1. Edited the original post. 2. Making the whole cabinet from plywood; what would be the advantages?

Comment: Advantages of plywood: 1) Cheap, 2) Dimensionally stable, 3) Cheap, 4) You can get a nice "cabinet grade" look without putting out a lot of cash.